# Convert Baire class $\xi$ function into Baire class one

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

Let $f$ be a real-valued baire class $\xi$ function.

In this [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.5724v2.pdf), page $24$, section $5$, before remark $5.1$, the author defined the set

$T_{f,\xi}=\{ \tau^{\prime} : \tau^{\prime} \supseteq \tau \text{ Polish}, \tau^{\prime} \subseteq \sum_{\xi}^0 (\tau), f \in B_1(\tau^{\prime})\}$

The set $T_{f,\xi}$ contains all topologies which convert $f$ into a Baire class one function.

Question: Can the set $T_{f, \xi}$ be infinite? I want to know this because I am trying to see whether the definition $5.3$ can attain its minimum or not.

Comment: In Definition 5.3, it seems that the $\rho_{\tau'}(f)$ ranges on $\omega_1$ (which is well ordered), so definitely the minimum is attained. Is that it?

Comment: so whenever we take a minimum over ordinals, the minimum is always attained?

Comment: Yes, every nonempty subset of a [wellorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order) has a minimum element. By the way, I observed that you are asking several questions concerning the same paper, and it seems that you are lacking some preliminaries for reading it. If you allow me, I'd recommend you reading Srivastava's [book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387984124), and _then_ [Kechris'](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387943749). Perhaps you can start directly with the second one.